# Multiple voltage and power output information on power adapter for Huawei Mateview

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to replace a broken (transparent oil-like fluid leaking) power supply adapter for a Huawei Mateview (28') monitor and multiple declarations for the output wattage and voltage are causing me confusion. [image]

If I can't find an official replacement, am I fine simply buynig a 135W & 20V adapter from a different brand with a USB-C plug? I tested it with a 96W, 20.5V adapter and it did not power on. The official website describes the power adapter as a 135W USB-C power adapter so I am guessing I need 135W then, but the label with multiple options was confusing.

Comment: The best method for finding out would be to contact Huawei tech support, as it guarantees 100% accurate info. I definitely wouldn't change to an adapter with wattage above 75W without contacting Huawei, as that's generally not possible when a DC power supply is involved since it would supply more voltage and/or amperage than the device is intended to handle. Since the power brick outputs at a maximum of 15V @ 5A [75W], a 135W supply is likely not okay - the brick is supplying either 3A or 5A at varying voltages, 5V or 9V @ 3A, 12V or 15V @ 5A. Ohm's Law: V[olts] x A[mps] = W[atts]  [`V*A = W`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just use any USB-C power adapter. This is a *proprietary* power adapter that supports both standardized USB-C Power Delivery (limited to 5 A *at 20 V*) as well as a proprietary extension to 6.75 A. You should get a new adapter from Huawei. It's the only way this is guaranteed to work.

[USB Power Delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#USB_Power_Delivery) supports negotiating voltage and current requirements, that's why all these combinations are printed in the power supply. However, more than 100 W must use higher voltages according to the spec.

Proprietary power supplies are very common with USB-C because many laptops need significantly more than 100 W. The higher-voltage specs however where only released in 2021.

Comment: .... I'm not *surprised* someone messed up a perfectly good standard but how would one know its not a standard voltage/amperiage combination?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Because it exceeds the maximum allowable USB-C connector current of 5 A.